# Oracle SYS.AUD$ Audit Actions

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2, auditing

We are running into tablespace issues as a result of a large SYS.AUD$ table.  Upon further investigation, we identified that 99% of the items in this table were SELECT actions

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from SYS.AUD$ where ACTION# = 3;

334698880

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYS.AUD$;

335176012
```

However, we cannot find **WHY** these are being logged.

- No system-wide auditing privileges set for SELECT (DBA_PRIV_AUDIT_OPTS)
- No system-wide statement options set for SELECT (DBA_STMT_AUDIT_OPTS)
- No specific objects being tracked (DBA_OBJ_AUDIT_OPTS)

Somehow these settings are being overridden.  Any suggestions with regards to places to look?

Comment: Could you dump out a few rows from sys.aud$ to see if they give you any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We have resolved the issue - the log-stamps allowed us to correlate the issue with a scheduled job:

1. Privilege auditing audits statements that use a system privilege - SQL statements that require the audited privilege to succeed are recorded
2. The auditing privilege EXEMPT ACCESS POLICY was enabled system wide
3. The EXEMPT ACCESS POLICY privilege allows a role to execute a SQL command without invoking any policy function that may be associated with the target database object
4. A scheduled job was executing a package that built database objects - this privilege was required to execute the package

The Auditing Section of the Oracle 11g Security Guide was extremely useful in this investigation
[Oracle 11g Security Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531.pdf)